# Hiding options in select box using Javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

```html
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <title>Home – dilo</title>

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/respond/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="dilo » Feed" href="http://localhost/dilog/?feed=rss2">
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="dilo » Comments Feed" href="http://localhost/dilog/?feed=comments-rss2">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="open-sans-css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C300%2C400%2C600&amp;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&amp;ver=4.1" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="dashicons-css" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.1" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="admin-bar-css" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.1" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="whisper-css" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-content/themes/whisper/css/main.css?ver=4.1" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="jquery-jplayer-css" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-content/themes/whisper/js/jplayer/skin/pixel-industry/pixel-industry.css?ver=4.1" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="jquery-prettyPhoto-css" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-content/themes/whisper/js/prettyPhoto/prettyPhoto.css?ver=4.1" type="text/css" media="all">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/dilog/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/dilog/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1"></script>
  <link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://localhost/dilog/xmlrpc.php?rsd">
  <link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml">
  <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.1">
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=941">
  <link rel="shortlink" href="http://localhost/dilog/?p=941">
  <style type="text/css">
    .recentcomments a {
      display: inline !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/css" media="print">
    #wpadminbar {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html {
      margin-top: 32px !important;
    }
    * html body {
      margin-top: 32px !important;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 782px) {
      html {
        margin-top: 46px !important;
      }
      * html body {
        margin-top: 46px !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <meta name="description" content="<p></p>">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#nav-container > select > option[2]").remove();
    console.log('hello');
  </script>
</head>

<body class="page page-id-941 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar orange wide header-right-sidebar header-right-sidebar-below customize-support">

  <div id="wrapper">
    <header id="header">
      <div class="clearfix inner">
        <div id="logo" class="left">
          <a href="http://localhost/dilog/" title="">
            <img alt="logo" src="http://localhost/dilog/wp-content/themes/whisper/img/logo.png">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div id="nav-container" class="right">


          <nav id="nav">
            <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu">
              <li id="menu-item-7779" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-941 current_page_item menu-item-7779"><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=941">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-7790" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children has-sub menu-item-7790"><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=1361">About Us</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-7788" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7788"><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=7576">Our Organisation</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-7787" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7787"><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=2021">Our History</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-7786" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7786"><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=2001">Our Training Philosophy</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-7785" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7785"><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=2041">Our Vision</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1702" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1702"><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=1331">Our Corporate Customers</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub menu-item-13"><a href="#">Media</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-7783" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7783"><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=1611">Images</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-7782" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7782"><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=1641">Videos</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-7784" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7784"><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=1591">In the News</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub menu-item-14"><a href="#">Apply Now</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-7789" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7789"><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=7583">Aviation English Training</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-7781" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7781"><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=1661">Aircraft Maintenance Training Programme</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-7780" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7780"><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=1541">Contact Us</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <select>
            <option value="">Go to...</option>
            <option value="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=941">Home</option>
            <option value="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=1361">About Us</option>
            <option value="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=7576">Our Organisation</option>
            <option value="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=2021">Our History</option>
            <option value="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=2001">Our Training Philosophy</option>
            <option value="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=2041">Our Vision</option>
            <option value="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=1331">Our Corporate Customers</option>
            <option value="#">Media</option>
            <option value="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=1611">Images</option>
            <option value="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=1641">Videos</option>
            <option value="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=1591">In the News</option>
            <option value="#">Apply Now</option>
            <option value="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=7583">Aviation English Training</option>
            <option value="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=1661">Aircraft Maintenance Training Programme</option>
            <option value="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=1541">Contact Us</option>
          </select>

          <div id="header-right" class="right below">
            <div class="widget right widget_search" id="search-2">
              <form class="search-form" method="get" action="http://localhost/dilog/">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Type and hit enter..." name="s">
                <input type="submit">
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="widget right widget_recent_entries" id="recent-posts-2">
              <h5 class="widget-title">Recent Posts</h5> 
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="http://localhost/dilog/?p=1">Hello world!</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="http://localhost/dilog/?p=4771">Training</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="http://localhost/dilog/?p=4731">Events</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="widget right widget_recent_comments" id="recent-comments-2">
              <h5 class="widget-title">Recent Comments</h5>
              <ul id="recentcomments">
                <li class="recentcomments"><span class="comment-author-link"><a href="https://wordpress.org/" rel="external nofollow" class="url">Mr WordPress</a></span> on <a href="http://localhost/dilog/?p=1#comment-1">Hello world!</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="widget right widget_archive" id="archives-2">
              <h5 class="widget-title">Archives</h5> 
              <ul>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?m=201501">January 2015</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?m=201406">June 2014</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="widget right widget_categories" id="categories-2">
              <h5 class="widget-title">Categories</h5> 
              <ul>
                <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?cat=1">Uncategorized</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="widget right widget_meta" id="meta-2">
              <h5 class="widget-title">Meta</h5> 
              <ul>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/">Site Admin</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;_wpnonce=2ea0aaf0fb">Log out</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?feed=rss2">Entries <abbr title="Really Simple Syndication">RSS</abbr></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?feed=comments-rss2">Comments <abbr title="Really Simple Syndication">RSS</abbr></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="https://wordpress.org/" title="Powered by WordPress, state-of-the-art semantic personal publishing platform.">WordPress.org</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="top-shadow">
      <div class="shadow"></div>
    </div>
    <section class="featured-title">
      <div class="container_12">
        <div class="grid_12">
          <div class="title left">
            <h1>Home</h1> 
          </div>

          <ul class="breadcrumbs right">
            <li><span itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a class="home" href="http://localhost/dilog/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">Home</span>
              </a>
              </span>
            </li>
            <li>/</li>
            <li>
              <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
   <a href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=941" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">Home</span>
              </a>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div id="main" class="container_12">

      <section id="content" class="hfeed blog-post-single grid_8" role="main">
        <article class="post-941 page type-page status-publish hentry page-content clearfix">
          <div class="post-body entry-content">
            <p></p>
            <div class="service-box">
              <i class=""></i>
              <h5>Aircraft Maintenance Training</h5>
              <p>
                <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2231" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/dts.png" alt="" width="137" height="96">
                <br>Approved Maintenance Training Organisation for fixed and rotary wing personnel.</p>

            </div>
            <a href="http://dilog.com.my/aviation-consultancy-2/">
              <div class="service-box">
                <i class=""></i>
                <h5>Aviation Consultancy</h5>
                <p>
                  <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2201" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Delta.png" alt="image006" width="137" height="96">
                  <br>The Group’s dynamic aviation consultancy arm.</p>

              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="service-box">
              <i class=""></i>
              <h5>Aviation English</h5>
              <p>
                <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4821" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Aviation-English-Logo-83.png" alt="Aviation-English-Logo-New">
                <br>Malaysia’s and the region’s only Aviation Language specialists.</p>

            </div>
            <p></p>
          </div>
          <div style="display:none">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="http://localhost/dilog/?page_id=941" title="Home" rel="bookmark">Home</a></h1> 
            <ul class="post-meta clearfix">
              <li>
                <time class="date updated" datetime="2014-03-26T09:19:11+00:00" pubdate="">March 26, 2014</time>
              </li>
              <li>
                <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://localhost/dilog/?author=2" title="View all posts by san cheam" rel="author">san cheam</a></span> 
              </li>
              <li>
                <span>Posted In: </span> 
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </article>


      </section>
      <aside class="grid_4" id="sidebar">
        <h5>Widget areas</h5>This is a sidebar (widget area). Please go to <a href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/widgets.php">Appearance → Widgets</a> to add widgets to this area</aside>
    </div>
    <!-- #main -->

    <footer id="footer">

      <div id="footer-sidebars" class="container_12">
        <div class="footer-widget grid_3">
          This is the Footer Sidebar 1 (widget area). Please go to <a href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/widgets.php">Appearance → Widgets</a> to add widgets to this area</div>
        <div class="footer-widget grid_3">
          This is the Footer Sidebar 2 (widget area). Please go to <a href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/widgets.php">Appearance → Widgets</a> to add widgets to this area</div>
        <div class="footer-widget grid_3">
          This is the Footer Sidebar 3 (widget area). Please go to <a href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/widgets.php">Appearance → Widgets</a> to add widgets to this area</div>
        <div class="footer-widget grid_3">
          This is the Footer Sidebar 4 (widget area). Please go to <a href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/widgets.php">Appearance → Widgets</a> to add widgets to this area</div>
      </div>
      <!-- #footer-sidebars -->

      <div id="footer-text">
        <div class="container_12">
          <div class="grid_6">Copyright ©2015 <a class="site-link" href="http://localhost/dilog/" title="dilo" rel="home">dilo</a>. All rights reserved.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- .copyright-container -->

    </footer>

  </div>
  <!-- #wrapper -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/dilog/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js?ver=4.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/dilog/wp-content/themes/whisper/js/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.min.js?ver=2.2.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/dilog/wp-content/themes/whisper/js/prettyPhoto/jquery.prettyPhoto.js?ver=3.1.5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/dilog/wp-content/themes/whisper/js/jquery.flexslider.js?ver=4.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/dilog/wp-content/themes/whisper/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.0-packed.js?ver=6.0.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var Whisper = {
      "navDefault": "Go to..."
    };
    /* ]]> */
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/dilog/wp-content/themes/whisper/js/script.js?ver=4.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var request, b = document.body,
        c = 'className',
        cs = 'customize-support',
        rcs = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)(no-)?' + cs + '(\\s+|$)');

      request = true;

      b[c] = b[c].replace(rcs, ' ');
      b[c] += (window.postMessage && request ? ' ' : ' no-') + cs;
    }());
  </script>
  <div id="wpadminbar" class="mobile" role="navigation">
    <a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="#wp-toolbar" tabindex="1">Skip to toolbar</a>
    <div class="quicklinks" id="wp-toolbar" role="navigation" aria-label="Top navigation toolbar." tabindex="0">
      <ul id="wp-admin-bar-root-default" class="ab-top-menu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/about.php" title="About WordPress"><span class="ab-icon"></span></a>
          <div class="ab-sub-wrapper">
            <ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-default" class="ab-submenu">
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-about"><a class="ab-item" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/about.php">About WordPress</a> 
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-external" class="ab-sub-secondary ab-submenu">
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-wporg"><a class="ab-item" href="https://wordpress.org/">WordPress.org</a> 
              </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-documentation"><a class="ab-item" href="http://codex.wordpress.org/">Documentation</a> 
              </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-support-forums"><a class="ab-item" href="https://wordpress.org/support/">Support Forums</a> 
              </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-feedback"><a class="ab-item" href="https://wordpress.org/support/forum/requests-and-feedback">Feedback</a> 
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-site-name" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/">dilo</a>
          <div class="ab-sub-wrapper">
            <ul id="wp-admin-bar-site-name-default" class="ab-submenu">
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-dashboard"><a class="ab-item" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/">Dashboard</a> 
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="wp-admin-bar-appearance" class="ab-submenu">
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-themes"><a class="ab-item" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/themes.php">Themes</a> 
              </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-customize" class="hide-if-no-customize"><a class="ab-item" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/customize.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdilog%2F%3Fpage_id%3D941">Customize</a> 
              </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-widgets"><a class="ab-item" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/widgets.php">Widgets</a> 
              </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-menus"><a class="ab-item" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/nav-menus.php">Menus</a> 
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-comments"><a class="ab-item" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/edit-comments.php" title="0 comments awaiting moderation"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span id="ab-awaiting-mod" class="ab-label awaiting-mod pending-count count-0">0</span></a> 
        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-content" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/post-new.php" title="Add New"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">New</span></a>
          <div class="ab-sub-wrapper">
            <ul id="wp-admin-bar-new-content-default" class="ab-submenu">
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-post"><a class="ab-item" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/post-new.php">Post</a> 
              </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-media"><a class="ab-item" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/media-new.php">Media</a> 
              </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-page"><a class="ab-item" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page">Page</a> 
              </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-portfolio"><a class="ab-item" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=portfolio">Portfolio</a> 
              </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-user"><a class="ab-item" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/user-new.php">User</a> 
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit"><a class="ab-item" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/post.php?post=941&amp;action=edit">Edit Page</a> 
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="wp-admin-bar-top-secondary" class="ab-top-secondary ab-top-menu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-search" class="admin-bar-search">
          <div class="ab-item ab-empty-item" tabindex="-1">
            <form action="http://localhost/dilog/" method="get" id="adminbarsearch">
              <input class="adminbar-input" name="s" id="adminbar-search" type="text" value="" maxlength="150">
              <input type="submit" class="adminbar-button" value="Search">
            </form>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-my-account" class="menupop with-avatar"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/profile.php" title="My Account">Howdy, tommy<img alt="" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6688e432d845dc1dd2426b6d1cb3bf8e?s=26&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D26&amp;r=G" class="avatar avatar-26 photo" height="26" width="26"></a>
          <div
          class="ab-sub-wrapper">
            <ul id="wp-admin-bar-user-actions" class="ab-submenu">
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-user-info">
                <a class="ab-item" tabindex="-1" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/profile.php">
                  <img alt="" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6688e432d845dc1dd2426b6d1cb3bf8e?s=64&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D64&amp;r=G" class="avatar avatar-64 photo" height="64" width="64"><span class="display-name">tommy</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit-profile"><a class="ab-item" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-admin/profile.php">Edit My Profile</a> 
              </li>
              <li id="wp-admin-bar-logout"><a class="ab-item" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;_wpnonce=2ea0aaf0fb">Log Out</a> 
              </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="http://localhost/dilog/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;_wpnonce=2ea0aaf0fb">Log Out</a>
  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

```
var id = document.getElementById('nav-container');
var sel = id.getElementsByTagName('select');
var option = sel.getElementsByTagName('option');
sel.remove(3);
```

Hi, I have the above Javascript to hide the 3rd option in the select box shown below: [image]

However, the last line, `sel.remove(3);` does not seem to work. I get an error of `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function?page_id=1361:188 (anonymous function)`

Did I use the wrong function? Any suggestions on how to modify my codes? Thanks.

Comment: What selectobject is? I think that you are meaning sel

Comment: @Ifch0o1 the answer was edited and the remove method is correct.

Comment: Could you post your code in fiddle? Also note that the first option is in index 0 so if you want to remove third you need to pass index 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's another script that was interfering with the script I have written, therefore I added a few lines before my script to make it load after my page is fully loaded:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#nav-container > select > option:eq(2)").remove();
  $("#nav-container > select > option:eq(7)").remove();
  $("#nav-container > select > option:eq(10)").remove();
});
```

And thus, this solved my problem. Thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 1):

`id.getElementsByTagName('select')` is returning a list of elements, of which there is only one. If there is only one select element, you should be able to change this:

```
var option = sel.getElementsByTagName('option');
sel.remove(3);
```

to this:

```
var option = sel[0].getElementsByTagName('option'); //was causing error
sel[0].remove(2); //assuming you want to remove 3rd element, not index 3
```

Comment: I have tried ur suggestion, however I'm still getting this:
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined'

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(sel);`?

Comment: [item: function, namedItem: function]
0: select
  0: option
  1: option
  2: option
  ...
lenght: 1

Comment: @TommyLee that's an odd result, what browser is that on? Should return a `HTMLCollection[]` even if none exist. Are you sure this error isn't coming from a different area of your code?

Comment: @jesse kernaghan I am using Chrome right now to test my codes... I have added console.log after the remove line to check if that line works... so far it the log did not show up

Comment: @RudySetiady I would but I'm using wordpress and these are non-accessible to me @_@

Comment: @JesseKernaghan I tried to use Firefox's console and it gave me this 'TypeError: sel[0] is undefined' with the updated answer and before the updated answer

Comment: @TommyLee Yes you can. Just share your rendered Page Source.

Comment: @TommyLee then there is something else at play. View the source of your website and provide relevant HTML. That exact js works in a simplified example shown here: http://codepen.io/jessekernaghan/pen/bNWKaB

Comment: @TommyLee Hmm... I didn't see "select" inside "nav-container". Is there any AJAX or something?

Comment: @RudySetiady I totally have no idea why the Select box isn't showing up in the source code... but it shows up when i use inspect element though

Comment: @TommyLee Please copy from the code when you inspect then.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan thanks I finally figured out the issue and solved it. Thanks for the time!

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("sel").remove(1);

var selAry = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

selAry[0].remove(0);
```

```html
<select id="sel">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

`document.getElementById("sel")` returns a collection of matched elements, so if you want to access one of them, use array index like `selAry[0]`.

Comment: @ianaya89 I've deleted that and point out the syntax problem.